installroot /boot files missing
Sequentially, I used dnf install --installroot for @core and kernel. Both say they installed and are listed in the rpmdb. The @core files are there but no kernel files exist in the installroot /boot. What am I missing?

Is your /boot a separate mount point where the installed files are now hidden on the root file system underneath the mount?

I checked that but no files in /boot mounted or not
